# Why does my text go back to left after adding the width so my background stays with text?

Tags: html, css, centering

So , when I add my *width* reference to my #information h1 id it completely **ignores** the **text-align: center;** reference and puts the text/background to the left instead of center

so basically i need help getting the headers centered with the proper background width so its not backgrounding whitespace

as you can tell im brand new - this is my first time experimenting with html and css - started my course a day or 2 ago

CSS

```
#information h1{
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    color: lightcoral;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    width: 130px;
    margin: 2px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px grey;
    font-size: 25px;
}
```

HTML

```
  <section id="information">
    <h1>Information</h1>
    <p>Currently starting my course on becoming a full stack engineer while working on a BS in Computer Science. Open to pretty much anything!<br>
      Looking for part time or full time work while I attend school and courses also open to any development projects!
    </p>
    <h1>Hobbies + More</h1>
```

**WITH WIDTH REFERENCE**

[headers how i want but not centered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnP0c.png)

**WITHOUT WIDTH REFERENCE**
[Headers without width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIJJ6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Centering text using `text-align: center` centers the text *within*  the element (in your case that's `h1`). If you set the elements `width` to 130px, it centers the text *within* those 130px (which might even be less wide than the text actually spans, or at least hardly more than that). The element itself still starts at the left side of its container (in your case the body).

Just don't set the width, as you did before.

Addition after comment:

You can use a `span` element for the text inside the `h1`, use `text-align: center` on the `h1` and all the other settings on the `span` inside it:

```css
#information h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
#information h1 span {
  padding: 2px 10px;
  font-family: Tahoma;
  color: lightcoral;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  border-radius: 25px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px grey;
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<section id="information">
  <h1><span>Information</span></h1>
  <p>Currently starting my course on becoming a full stack engineer while working on a BS in Computer Science. Open to pretty much anything!<br> Looking for part time or full time work while I attend school and courses also open to any development projects!
  </p>
  <h1><span>Hobbies + More</span></h1>
</section>
```

Comment: then the background goes across the whitespaces and not just behind the text - as you can see in the pictures

Comment: @ツBren Please note the addition to my answer

Comment: Thank you! I am now using this method since it seems a bit easier to manage than other and can be used for more ... again I apprecaite the help alot

Answer (score 0):

Give h1 a `display: inline;` by default h1 use `display: block;`.
read difference between them [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6821497/what-is-the-difference-between-a-div-and-a-span-with-displayblock).
Apart from that I have horizontal `padding`.
You can set style for `p` tag as you need

```css
    #information h1{
        text-align: center;
        font-family: Tahoma;
        color: lightcoral;
        background-color: whitesmoke;
        margin: 2px;
        padding:0 10px;
        border-radius: 25px;
        box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px grey;
        font-size: 25px;
        display: inline;
    }
    #information {
        text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
    <section id="information">
        <h1>Information</h1>
        <p>Currently starting my course on becoming a full stack engineer while working on a BS in Computer Science. Open to pretty much anything!<br>
          Looking for part time or full time work while I attend school and courses also open to any development projects!
        </p>
        <h1>Hobbies + More</h1>
    </section>
```

Comment: thank you for the help brother will learn more about the new references .. appreciate it alot - this is solution to what i was looking for

Comment: Bren do accept the answer with upvote 
it really helps :)

Comment: indeed - waiting for it to allow me to - again appreciate the help!

Comment: Note: This also centers the text in the `p` tags (and everything else that would be added)...

Answer (score 0):

You are using the text align property in the h1 instead of the section. You can find more information about text align here [text-align](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/text-align)

You can use it like this:

```
#information {
    text-align: center; /* Center-align the content within the section */
}

#information h1 {
    display: inline-block; /* Make the h1 an inline block to have only the content's width */
    font-family: Tahoma;
    color: lightcoral;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    margin: 2px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px grey;
    font-size: 25px;
    padding: 5px 10px; /* Add some padding for better aesthetics */
}
```

You may also want to check te correct use of h1,h2,h3 etc in order to get along whit Google SEO. I hope it helps, keep in the good path my friend.

Comment: thanks brother! i appreciate the insights and help - i had the text align in the id of the section as well but since #information h1 is more specific thought id need it there too!